# Including a Java code snippet by method name, not line number

Tags: listings, java

I am currently writing documents that contain large amounts of references to source code, in which I would typically include a complete method at a time.

```
/*
...
*/

public class MyClass {

    public MyClass(String... someArguments) {
        /*
        ...
        */
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Some information on this specific instance.";
    }
}
```

Currently, I would do this for example as follows:

`\lstinputlisting[firstnumber=13,firstline=13,lastline=16]{./path/MyClass.java}}`

This source code is kept in separate files that are being edited in parallel, resulting in the methods I want to include moving or changing its line count. The method itself might be rewritten to include additional lines, annotations, etc.

A simple addition at the beginning of the document (such as an additional import) results in all references to these lines needing to be updated.

Ideally I would like to do something like this:

`\importmethod{toString()}{./path/MyClass.java}`

or possibly with other options/syntax:

`\importmethod[annotations=true]{MyClass > toString()}{./path/MyClass.java}`

That would always look for the complete section of this method including annotations, JavaDoc comments, etc. as long as the method signature does not change.

Does this already exist in some package or could this be achieved with a macro?

Comment: You could use text markers, see 5.7 Arbitrary linerange markers in the listings documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I was always looking at an outdated version of the reference, this made me search for the
[current version of the documentation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf#subsection.5.7).

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?

Comment: I ended up not using anything dynamic and continued with fixed line ranges as I was not able to modify the original source.